# Метод не очищает функцию

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeBuffer(){
    var d = [];
    var r = '';

    function buffer(){        
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            d.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        return d;
    }

    buffer.clear = function(){
        var s = d.join();
        return  s = '';
    }
    return buffer
}

var s = makeBuffer();

s(12);
s(112);
s.clear();
console.log(s())
```

Comment: Объясните, что делают эти две строчки: `var s = d.join();
  return  s = '';` И зачем нужна первая при наличии второй. А, и заодно - что такое "очищать функцию".

Comment: @Igor массив превращаем в строку и присваиваем в переменную s; s присваиваем пустую строку

Comment: Можно узнать - зачем?

Comment: @Igor чтобы очистить

Comment: Очистить *что*?

Comment: очистить массив d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function makeBuffer() {
  var d = [];

  function buffer() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      d.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return d;
  }

  buffer.clear = function() {
    d.splice(0); // !!!
    return d;
  }

  return buffer;
}

var s = makeBuffer();

s(12);
s(112);
s.clear();
console.log(s())
```

Comment: d.splice(0, d.length);  у массива d вызываем метод splice где 0 указываем с какого элемента удалять, а d.length это длина массива + 1

Comment: почему происходит удаление ?

Comment: @Leks Это Вы сейчас с кем разговариваете?

Comment: сам собою если не против присоединяйтесь

Comment: @Leks Вам найти статью, объясняющую, что делает функция `splice` и как ее использовать?

Comment: не надо дядя я уже прочитал вот  здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#metod-splice

Comment: думал 2 аргумент у splice удаляет: например если массив из 5 элементов то если  splice(0, 5) удалит 5 элемент

Comment: теперь понял splice(0, 5) удалит 5 элементов начиная с нуля

Comment: получается если d.splice(0, d.length) length - это коллекция элементов  + 1 то не будет ошибки правильно ?

Comment: @Leks Почему Вы все время пишете "+ 1"? `d.length` это просто длина массива.

Comment: d.length это  длина массива которое начинается с нуля поэтому length это длина массива плюс 1

Comment: Длина length – не количество элементов массива, а последний индекс + 1

Comment: так написано https://learn.javascript.ru/array#osobennosti-raboty-length

Comment: @Leks "которое"? Что начинается с нуля? По Вашей ссылке написан бред. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: спасибо дядя ...

Comment: @Igor на счет длины массива ошибка все-таки на  developer.mozilla. В таком простом примере `var a = []; a[10] = 0; for(var i in a) console.log(i);` вы обнаружите только один элемент

Comment: Все не правы :-D [The value of the **length** property is numerically greater than the name of every own property whose name is an array index;](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects) @AlexanderLonberg